# Applying a mask to a dataframe, but only over a certain range inside the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I currently have some code that uses a mask to calculate the mean of values that are overloads, and values that are baseline values. It does this over the entire length of the dataframe. However, now I want to only apply this to a certain range in the dataframe column, between `first` and `last` values (ie, a specified region in the column, dictated by user input). Here is my code as it stands:

```
mask_number = 5
no_overload_cycles = 1
hyst = pd.DataFrame({"test":[12, 4, 5, 4, 1, 3, 2, 5, 10, 9, 7, 5, 3, 6, 3, 2 ,1, 5, 2]})

list_test = []
for i in range(0,len(hyst)-1,mask_number):
    for x in range(no_overload_cycles):
        list_test.append(i+x)
    
mask = np.array(list_test)

print(mask)
[0 1 5 10 15 20]

first = 4
last = 17
regression_area = hyst.iloc[first:last]

mean_range_overload = regression_area.loc[np.where(mask == regression area.index)]['test'].mean()
mean_range_baseline = regression_area.drop(mask[first:last])['test'].mean()
```

So the overload mean would be be cycles, 5, 10, and 15 in `test`, and the baseline mean would be from positions 4 to 17, excluding 5, 10 and 15. This would be my expected output from this:

```
print (mean_range_overload)
4

print(mean_range_baseline)
4.545454
```

However, the `no_overload_cycles` value can change, and may for example, be 3, which would then create a mask of this:

```
mask_number = 5
no_overload_cycles = 3
hyst = pd.DataFrame({"test":[12, 4, 5, 4, 1, 3, 2, 5, 10, 9, 7, 5, 3, 6, 3, 2 ,1, 5, 2]})

list_test = []
for i in range(0,len(hyst)-1,mask_number):
    for x in range(no_overload_cycles):
        list_test.append(i+x)

mask = np.array(list_test)

print(mask)
[0 1 2 5 6 7 10 11 12 15 16 17 20]
```

So the `mean_range_overload` would be mean of the values at 5,6,7,10,11,12,15,16,17, and the `mean_range_baseline` would be the values inbetween these, in the range of `first` and `last` in the dataframe column.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe I understand your question, but could you add some expected results? We could probably help you get your code a little more optimized as well without a loop if we could just see what you start with and what you end with and simplified explanation.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've included what I expect the results to be from this code.

Comment: Couple of questions. You mention in your explination 5,10,and 15 would this not also include 0 in the index? Also where did the mean of 10.66 come from? It looked like to me when you get the sum of 0,5,10,15 it comes out to be 24/4 = 6 or am I missing something?

Comment: No, it wouldn't include 0 as that is not in the range that is specified by `first` and `last` (the range of the dataframe column I want to apply the mask over). However, the value was wrong so I have edited it to be correct.

Comment: Hi, I think you should have a look at [ask] and try to produce a [mcve] including the expected output. 
Having a smaller and clean example will help a lot to focus on the important steps. Plus it would be easier for you to get quality answers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `no_overload_cycles == 1` always, you can simply use slice objects to index the `DataFrame`.

Say you wish to, in your example, specifically pick cycles 5, 10 and 15 and use them as overload. Then you can get them by doing `df.loc[5:15:5]`.
On the other hand, if you wish to pick the 5th, 10th and 15th cycles from the range you selected, you can get them by doing `df.iloc[5:15+1:5]` (`iloc` does not include the right index, so we add one). No loops required.

As mentioned in the comments, your question is slightly confusing, and it'd be helpful if you gave a better description and some expected results; in general I'd also advise you to decouple the domain-specific part of your problem before asking it in a forum, since not everyone knows what you mean by "overload", "baseline", "cycles" *etc*. I'm not commenting that since I still don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: `no_overload_cycles` can be any value, it won't always be 1, it may be 2, 3, up to 5. Thanks for your help, but I can't use that solution as it may change. I've tried to clean up the explanation and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed a few of the variables, so what I called a "mask" is not exactly what you called a mask, but I reckon this is what you were trying to make:

```py
mask_length = 5
overload_cycles_per_mask = 3
df = pd.DataFrame({"test": [12, 4, 5, 4, 1, 3, 2, 5, 10, 9, 7, 5, 3, 6, 3, 2 ,1, 5, 2]})

selected_range = (4, 17)
overload_indices = []
baseline_indices = []
# `range` does not include the right hand side so we add one
# ideally you would specify the range as (4, 18) instead
for i in range(selected_range[0], selected_range[1]+1):
    if i % mask_length < overload_cycles_per_mask:
        overload_indices.append(i)
    else:
        baseline_indices.append(i)


print(overload_indices)
print(df.iloc[overload_indices].test.mean())
print(baseline_indices)
print(df.iloc[baseline_indices].test.mean())
```

Basically, the `DataFrame` rows inside `selected_range` are divided into segments of length `mask_length`, each of which has their first `overload_cycles_per_mask` elements marked as overload, and any others, as baseline.

With that, you get two lists of indices, which you can directly pass to `df.iloc`, as according to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas-dataframe-iloc) it supports a list of integers.

Here is the output for `mask_length = 5` and `overload_cycles_per_mask = 1`:

```
[5, 10, 15]
4.0
[4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17]
4.545454545454546
```

And here is for `mask_length = 5` and `overload_cycles_per_mask = 3`:

```
[5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17]
3.6666666666666665
[4, 8, 9, 13, 14]
5.8
```

I do believe calling this a single mask makes things more confusing. In any case, I would tuck the logic for getting the indices away in some separate function to the one which calculates the mean.